# Get driving distance between two points using Google Maps API

Tags: php

I'm trying to get **driving** distance between two points using Google Maps API. Now, I have code which get direct distance:

This function get lat and lng:

```
function get_coordinates($city, $street, $province)
{
    $address = urlencode($city.','.$street.','.$province);
    $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=Poland";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $response_a = json_decode($response);
    $return = array('lat' => $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lat, 'long' => $long = $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lng);

    return $return;
}
```

This function calculate distance between two points based on lat & lng:

```
function getDistanceBetweenPoints($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {
    $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
    $miles = (sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2))) + (cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta)));
    $miles = acos($miles);
    $miles = rad2deg($miles);
    $miles = $miles * 60 * 1.1515;
    $kilometers = $miles * 1.609344;
    return $kilometers;
}
```

This function print distance by kilometers:

```
function get_distance($lat1, $lat2, $long1, $long2)
{
    /* These are two points in New York City */
    $point1 = array('lat' => $lat1, 'long' => $long1);
    $point2 = array('lat' => $lat2, 'long' => $long2);

    $distance = getDistanceBetweenPoints($point1['lat'], $point1['long'], $point2['lat'], $point2['long']);
    return $distance;
}
```

Usage:

```
$coordinates1 = get_coordinates('Katowice', 'Korfantego', 'Katowicki');
$coordinates2 = get_coordinates('Tychy', 'Jana Pawła II', 'Tyski');

echo 'Distance: <b>'.round(get_distance($coordinates1['lat'], $coordinates2['lat'], $coordinates1['long'], $coordinates2['long']), 1).'</b> km';
```

But this code get direct distance. I need driving distance. 
How I can get driving distance using google maps API?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [distance matrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/#DistanceMatrixRequests) API?

Comment: @VivekPradhan ye. This was useful: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=50.1112251,18.9903966&destinations=50.1369031,19.1012599&mode=driving&language=pl-PL
Thanks!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

OK, I found solution using distance matrix: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/#DistanceMatrixRequests

This function get lat & lng from city, adress, province:

```
function get_coordinates($city, $street, $province)
{
    $address = urlencode($city.','.$street.','.$province);
    $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=Poland";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $response_a = json_decode($response);
    $status = $response_a->status;

    if ( $status == 'ZERO_RESULTS' )
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        $return = array('lat' => $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lat, 'long' => $long = $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lng);
        return $return;
    }
}
```

This function calculate driving distance and travel time duration:

```
function GetDrivingDistance($lat1, $lat2, $long1, $long2)
{
    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$lat1.",".$long1."&destinations=".$lat2.",".$long2."&mode=driving&language=pl-PL";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $response_a = json_decode($response, true);
    $dist = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
    $time = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'];

    return array('distance' => $dist, 'time' => $time);
}
```

Usage:

```
$coordinates1 = get_coordinates('Tychy', 'Jana Pawła II', 'Śląskie');
$coordinates2 = get_coordinates('Lędziny', 'Lędzińska', 'Śląskie');
if ( !$coordinates1 || !$coordinates2 )
{
    echo 'Bad address.';
}
else
{
    $dist = GetDrivingDistance($coordinates1['lat'], $coordinates2['lat'], $coordinates1['long'], $coordinates2['long']);
    echo 'Distance: <b>'.$dist['distance'].'</b><br>Travel time duration: <b>'.$dist['time'].'</b>';
}
```

Return:

Distance: 11,2 km
Travel time duration: 15 min

Comment: wat does 11,2km defines here?

Comment: @humbledust just change the language in URL

Answer (score 17):

You can do this by using Google Distance Matrix API:

```
// $details = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco&mode=driving&sensor=false";

    //you can also pass latitude/longitude values in origins


   $details = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=41.43206,-81.38992&destinations=San+Francisco&mode=driving&sensor=false";


    $json = file_get_contents($details);

    $details = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    echo "<pre>"; print_r($details); echo "</pre>";
```

Here is the link of Google Distance Matrix API :- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/?csw=1

Answer (score 6):

This is the method I got. In it, you can enter any manual distance from sessions or database.

```
$origin      = urlencode($_SESSION['source1']);
$destination = urlencode($_SESSION['dest1']);

$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$origin&destinations=$destination&key=Your api key";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response_a = json_decode($response, true);
?>
```

Now the tough part was how to show distance. Well, with research, I got this answer:

```
<div>
     <?php echo $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text']; ?>
</div>
```

You can print this result anywhere. It's working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Distance matrix API will do job then no need to calculate coordinates by using address and then Distance!!

Here is the API 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=orginaddress&destinations=destinationaddress&key=YOUR_API_KEY

PHP Code :

```
$ch = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=orginaddress&destinations=destinationaddress&key=YOUR_API_KEY";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response_a = json_decode($response, true);
//print_( $response_a );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Google Distance Matrix API. Here is a sample HTML, PHP code in bellow. Here you must change the 'YOUR_API_KEY' with your app key.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <label>Origin:</label> <input type="text" name="o" placeholder="Enter Origin location" required> <br><br>
            <label>Destination:</label> <input type="text" name="d" placeholder="Enter Destination location" required> <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Calculate distance & time" name="submit"> <br><br>
        </form>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $origin = $_POST['o']; $destination = $_POST['d'];
            $api = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=".$origin."&destinations=".$destination."&key=YOUR_API_KEY");
            $data = json_decode($api);
        ?>
            <label><b>Distance: </b></label> <span><?php echo ((int)$data->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->value / 1000).' Km'; ?></span> <br><br>
            <label><b>Travel Time: </b></label> <span><?php echo $data->rows[0]->elements[0]->duration->text; ?></span> 

        <?php } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Edit question and add some explanation also