# Calculate the distance between two location using google map api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a requirement to calculate and print the distance from current location to given destination.  As per my understanding, i can achieve this by google Map api.

So, I will have to pass only destination location and api will the map as well as distance.

For that I have configured on google and got the below link, I am not able to understand how to use this, but in below url I am passing the source and destination, but I don't want to pass the source, it should be taken current location as source.

Is it possible to print the distance on web page?

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=kanpur&destination=lucknow&key=%20AIzaSyCeBdq7rr-R7w7vZCXscLWgEDb3oO9CUhw

Comment: Do you want driving distance (by road) or straight line distance (as the crow flies)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate distance between two points in google maps V3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502590/calculate-distance-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get driving distance between two points using Google Maps API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29003118/get-driving-distance-between-two-points-using-google-maps-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for a [Directions service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) but since:

> but I don't want to pass the source, it should be taken current
>   location as source.

below is provided the *modified* example from [Directions service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) page that demonstrates how to specify current location for Directions service

```js
function initMap() {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 7,
        center: { lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65 }
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    var printRoute = function () {
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    };

    getCurrentLocation(function (loc) {
        if (loc != null) {
            document.getElementById('startInner').value = loc.toString();
            document.getElementById('start').innerHTML = 'Current location';
            map.setCenter(loc);
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('start').innerHTML = 'Current location not found';
            document.getElementById('btnCalc').disabled = true;
        }  
    });

    document.getElementById('btnCalc').addEventListener('click', printRoute);
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    directionsService.route({
        origin: document.getElementById('startInner').value,
        destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, function (response, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
    });
}


function getCurrentLocation(complete) {  
    // Try W3C Geolocation (Preferred)
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var location = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            complete(location);
        }, function () {
            complete(null);
        });
    }
    else {
        complete(null);
    }
}
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#map {
    height: 100%;
}

#floating-panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 25%;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="floating-panel">
        <b>Start: </b>
        <span id="start">Current Location</span>
        <b>End: </b>
        <input id="end" type="text" ></input>
        <input id="startInner" type="hidden"></input>
        <button id="btnCalc">Print route</button>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/78bbuzf7/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to do this:

Code:

```
var p1 = new google.maps.LatLng(20, 9.4);
var p2 = new google.maps.LatLng(60.23, 9.7);

function distanceTwoPoints(p3, p4){
  return (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p3, p4) / 1000); //dividing by 1000 to get Kilometers
}
alert(distanceTwoPoints(p1, p2));
```

Fiddle example **(UPDATED)**: https://jsfiddle.net/wexd3spp/12/

If you want to print it on the page I suggest to use the standard output method:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = distanceTwoPoints(p1,p2)+" Km";
```

Here is what the documentation says about it:

> The distance between two points is the length of the shortest path
>   between them. This shortest path is called a geodesic. On a sphere all
>   geodesics are segments of a great circle. To compute this distance,
>   call computeDistanceBetween(), passing it two LatLng objects.

Comment: Thanks eugen..but what is in LatLng(), where will i give the values (source and destination)??

Comment: LatLng() is the latitude and longitude of a point (like x and y coordinates). You can always give the values inside a <input> html tag.

Comment: @sumit I shouldn't be helping so much but check out the updated fiddle.