# How to get json file from google maps server?

Tags: php, json, google-maps

I'm trying to make simply trip calculator, and i am here and don't know what to do next, also it seemed to work, but it doesn't.

So up there is a question, becouse this code should give me a json file, looking for some advice guys :3

```
<form  action="#" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="origin" value="" placeholder="Origin">
  <input type="text" name="destination" value="" placeholder="Destination">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="wyslij">
</form>

<?php
//https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Disneyland&destination=Universal+Studios+Hollywood4&key=YOUR_API_KEY
define("YOUR_API_KEY","AIzaSyDqFsGPY9bSMtjh8S3oYAr1o0cPkBgCV1g");

$origin = $_GET["origin"];
$destination = $_GET["destination"];

if(isset($origin) && isset($destination) && !empty($origin) && !empty($destination)){
  $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=".$origin."&destination=".$destination."&key=".YOUR_API_KEY;
  //echo $url;
  if(file_put_contents($url,true)) echo '<p>DZIALA</p>';
  $str = file_put_contents($url,true);
  $json = json_decode($str, true);
  echo '<pre>' . print_r($json, true) . '</pre>';
}
else{
  echo "sth";
}
?>
```

Comment: when i paste link made by this form i can see this json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you use Distance Matrix API from Google - is much easy to use?
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start

and what you asked was discussed here:

[Get driving distance between two points using Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29003118/get-driving-distance-between-two-points-using-google-maps-api)